# How to strip tags but keep unmatched `<` codes

Tags: php, mysqli

I am developing a php chat system with mysqli where one of my chat code is `<3` just like Facebook.

**Problem**

My problem is that when I do not add strip tags to the message sent by a member, if the member posts `<script> alert('What is this'); ?>`, the raw text is displayed. But when I add

```
 <?php $message = strip_tags($message); ?>
```

...it strips the tag from the message, BUT also breaks `<3`. I have also tried htmlentities and htmlspecialchars, but they both convert `<3` into its html form.

**QUESTION**

How can I strip my message from tags but still allow codes using unmatched `<`, such as `<3`? For example `<script>` should be allowed **but not** `</script>`, and `<?php ?>` **should not be allowed** but `<anything` should be allowed.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity, but there are a few points I wasn't certain on. What do you mean when you say that `<3` is "not able to work"? (I substituted "breaks," which makes sense but is too vague.) Also, it's not quite clear (to me, at least) what the common factor is between `<anything` and `<script>` that makes them permissible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not what you've asked. But maybe `htmlentities()` would work for you.

It converts some special characters to HTML entities so it will print `<string>` literally, but will not execute it.

```
<?php $message = htmlentities($message); ?>
```

If your message is:

```
<script> alert('What is this');</script>
```

It will not create a pop-up, it will show on screen the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace `<3` with `&#60;3` and strip_tags will not break it.
You can see html codes table here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat: I have never used PHP or MSQLI, so it's possible I have no idea what I'm talking about.)

Have you considered pre-processing messages to scan them for the character-combinations you wish to "save" from tag-stripping *before* passing the string to the tag-stripper?

I don't know how the tag-stripper works, but I imagine that it includes some way to escape `<` characters so that they are not recognized as tags. If you search your message strings for the sequence `<3` and insert `\` so that they become `\<3`, what does that tag stripper do? Will that fit your needs?

If there is no way of escaping the special codes, you could simply replace them with something that doesn't look like HTML. For instance,

User's message: `I <3 <b>You</b>!`
Pre-processed version (search-and-replace): `I ###HEART### <b>You</b>!`
Pass to tag-stripper: `I ###HEART### You!`
Finally, replace `###HEART###` with the heart symbol.

**EDIT:** As per Petroff's answer, it's probably better to use `&#60;3` (which is an html code for `<3`).

---

**IF the symbols you are outputting are unicode points**, e.g. if `<3` is supposed to become `U-2665`, why not just perform *that* search-and-replacement first? The unicode point will not include `<`, so it will not be recognized as a tag.